# TFS 2012 - Refuse checkin when build agent failed

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

how can I do to make the checkin of developers being refused when tfs build agent failed ?
Is it possible, what s the best way ?

Thank's by advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Gated Builds are designed specifically for this purpose.  Just setup a TFS Build and set the trigger to be Gated Build.  Now when developers check-in it will prompt them that they need to pass the Gated Build first.

[image]